# Oracle rounding for getting exact value

Tags: oracle11g

I want to round the below value in oracle and need to get same value as 99.23659.

```
select round(99.23659,x) from dual
```

And the x value is should not 5 or more. What value to pass here.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what you're asking really. If you want to get the same value why call `round` at all? If you want to round any value to five decimal places then x is 5, [but the docs say that](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions155.htm).

Comment: Thanks!My actual requirement is; I need to make this as configurable. When I pass the round value, it should use it. There are some scenarios for which I do not want to round the number; it should get the exact number. Consider two set of data; X and Y. For Y, I need to pass 2 as round value and for X, I need to pass a round value where it will get the exact number. Please suggest if this is possible.

Comment: Pass from where? You can use a bind variable for `x` and let the client decide whether to send a fixed value like 2, or a calculated number based on the current number of digits after the decimal point (or some magic high number like 99). Depends how and where you're doing this though.